# Cause of Evil, as per Theistic Vedanta?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

If Parameshvara is svatantra karta as per Vedanta, and if everything pre decided as per lords will, whatever we're doing is God doing actually, so is he the Cause of Evil

Comment: Haha, btw who is the founder of theistic Vedanta? Adi Ramanujashankaradhwa āchārya? :)

Comment: Whatever you see good or evil is contained in the Supreme Para Brahma. There is nothing in the whole existence which is separated from the Para Brahma. Evil is but another expansion of some power of Para Brahma just like goodness, kindness, satisfaction , prosperity, bad luck, sorrow, happiness are .

Comment: What is theistic Vedanta? Iswara exists in Vedanta. Why this "theistic"?

Comment: @TheDestroyer What I mean by Theistic Vedanta, is the subschools of vedanta's that expound bhakti to be the Only supreme mean to attain the supreme being, while Vijnanabhikshu believed yoga as per that of Patanjal's are the only supreme means to attain Brahmanhood, even yadava prakasha wasn't that inclined to bhakti thought....

Comment: @IndranilAmalDutta I think Vijnanabhikshu said there's unity between Vedanta, Yoga and Samkhya.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Sir pls refer brahma sutras, it says evil can't be an attribute of the divine nor he creates evil because thereby he then can't be an object of supreme order

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes you're absolutely right, but he says yoga that of Patanjal's is the utmost order of attaining the supreme, while bhakti can provide us some amount of divine intellect through which we could hv a better understanding of Brahman, who is Vishnu according him, but dat doesn't make him a vaishnava, because all vaishnava inclined vedantic schools, have commonly propounded bhakti to be supreme order of attaining unison with the ultimate.

Comment: So what is evil and good for that matter? Nothing can be called Evil or Good. Sattva , Rajas, and Tamas are part of same Para Brahma. Just imagine, even if we consider evil , then if evil is not in Para Brahma it will mean Evil is something apart from ParaBrahma, and this contradicts the very nature of Para Brahma that it is all pervading single sole supreme entity.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Dear Sir, Evil is a mere conception and not a kind of a gross entity like tri-gunas, Evil is sometimes is also called Avidya or Ignorance as per all Schools both of ortho's and hetero's which is also cannot be a part of Brahman, for if we say Avidya is an attribute of Brahman, then it'll once again contradict the shrutis which say "Satyam, Jnanam, Anantam Brahman", Brahman is pure knowledge how can it hv Ignorance as an attribute of it. BDW r u d same person who've once initiated a whatsapp forum on Bhagavat Gita?

Comment: No I am not that whatsapp person. And, I do not mean only Para Brahma is responsible for evil. I just meant to point at all encompassing nature if Para Brahma. So if Brahman can create good, it can create bad too. Whatever is in universe, at the end goes down to Para Brahman only, as it is the sole unseconded entity. Maya which is part of Brahman created good, evil , happiness , sorrow, et cetera to keep us getting bewildered in this world. When you are graced, Vidya Maya plays you into spiritual path. At end, even Vidya Maya goes and you are one with Brahman. – Devi Puraana.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Brahman does not creates universe, but the Universe is What we see and see not, both r itself being the very supreme Brahman, but it's in reality it's just a Vikara as in Modification---Mandukya Karika of Agama prakaran, Brahman has no need to create the Universe at all, for it wud be then concluded that Brahman has Vasanas like us---Brahma Sutras, So there's actually no reason that there wud be a creation of good and bad, But   u actually didn't understood my Question, Brahman is said 2 b good 4 d essence of beingness of all sorts of happiness in reality is d very Brahman.

Comment: @AnuragSingh What we know as evil or bad is actually nothing but Suffering, now dis wud sound a bit buddhist but wat's cause of Evil as in Suffering? If everything  happens under d very will of God, then why is he not directing to us to d spiritual path letting us to know our true nature & den liberate us.

Comment: IndranilAmalDutta , all scriptures have different opinions and ideas. Now just think, why did Brahman take form of Shiva, Devi, Vishnu, Ganesh et cetera? How can that Brahman have no will who is the very root of all things material or abstract? And why does Brahman need to create good as well? Brahman is both attached and detached to this world. Brahman can not be understood by words or arguments or contradiction.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Hmmmm..... You're Absolutely Right Brahman can never be understood completely by the limited minds of jivas like us(Human), The Scriptures only tell that they at there best can only proove dat he exists, but it can never be known even by d sages and d seers.

Answer (score 6):

You're talking about the well known ["Problem of Evil"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/) in Western Philosophy.

This is discussed in detail in the Vedanta Sutras, in particular in the sutra *वैषम्यनैर्घृण्ये न, सापेक्षत्वात्, तथा हि दर्शयति*. The basic position is that it is not possible to blame God for evil on account of partiality or cruelty because He is an impartial observer and facilitator of events in accordance with past Karma of the individual. For the Ramanuja position on this Sutra, see [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48203.htm). For the position of Adi Sankara Bhagavatpada, see [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34173.htm).

One may argue as indeed [others have](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1398356?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that this merely pushes the causal agent of the evil to a previous birth and by extension to the very first birth. However this doesn't fit into Vedanta because the number of past lifetimes is not finite and karma is beginning-less axiomatically. If you accept this axiom as truth then it becomes impossible to find an answer that is satisfactory because it challenges our notions of causality (not too unlike speed of light, time dilation and other relativistic physics).

In Visistadvaita at least it is commonly thought that we as mere mortals are incapable of understanding the answer.